# Determine overlapping components in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel loaded on top of JXTreeTable. I want to determine if JPanel overlaps a particular cell of JXTreeTable. I tried retriving the X and Y components and comparing them. However when I check the JPanel's minimum X and Y co-ordinates, they are always 0.0. I am not able to figure out that. Is there any other than than just comparing the co-ordinate values?

Comment: Please show an SSCCE that demonstrates the problem (having trouble to understand what you mean by _overlaps_ - in a JLayer/edPane or OverlayLayout or ... ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `Rectangle` to help determine if the components are overlapping.

ie

```
Rectangle panelBounds = panel.getBounds();
Rectangle cellBounds = getRowBounds(row); // getPathBounds(path);
if (panelBounds.intersects(cellBounds)) {
    // We have a collision
}
```

Now, you bigger problem is, the X/Y return value always been 0.  This means that the `Rectangle` return by the `getBounds` method will also return x/y of 0.

You will need share some code to show us how you laying out this component.

Answer (score 1):

you can to determine the `JComponents` coordinates only if:

- is already visible on the screen
- after called method `pack()`

for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)